# run jprogress bar on jframe load

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jprogressbar

I am creating swing application. I am using netbeans, I have added jprogress bar on container but I have no idea how to start. I need jprogressbar to show loading. I have created a jframe which contains jprogressbar. on jframe load I want to start jprogressbar and run for say 5 seconds. close that frame and want to open new jframe.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399971/make-splash-screen-with-progress-bar-like-eclipse or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: @Ashish..if you found helpful you can upvote my answer.. thanks anyway..

Comment: not eligible for vote up yet. need 15 reps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for loading Screen.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class demo extends Frame implements ActionListener
{      
   public demo() {}
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    try {
         JWindow window = new JWindow();
         window.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/demo/gimpsplash.gif"), SwingConstants.CENTER));
         window.setBounds(500, 150, 300, 200);
         window.setVisible(true);
         try 
         {
             Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {}
         window.setVisible(false);
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         frame.add(new JLabel("Welcome Swing application for Ashish.."));
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setSize(300,200);
         window.dispose();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Kapildemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Replace ImageIcon path `ImageIcon("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/demo/gimpsplash.gif")` with your path and you done..

Thanks..