# How do I use SplashScreen without throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, splash-screen

No matter what I try, `SplashScreen.getSplashScreen()` is **always** `null`.

From searching online I see that this is a common issue, and that it has something to do with not giving the `SplashScreen` an image to use... Therefore, in navigating the methods it seemed to me that `setImageURL(URL)` should be used. This is still not working.

There are similar questions on SO, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089359/java-6-splash-screen), which are not helpful and seem to suggest using a myriad of plugins or creating such a class from scratch extending from `Frame`. Even the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) is cryptic, and doesn't outline each logical step in using `SplashScreen` correctly...

If it is not possible or needlessly difficult to use `SplashScreen`, is there any alternative to doing this? Or has anyone hacked out a simple approach to this problem?

---

Here is my attempt:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.SplashScreen;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 */
public final class MainGUI implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws IllegalStateException 
     * @throws NullPointerException 
     */
    private final static void showSplashScreen() throws NullPointerException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        Graphics2D graphics = splash.createGraphics();

        // adding image here:
        URL imageSource = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Space_Shuttle_Atlantis_approaching_the_Kennedy_Space_Center_to_land_following_STS-122.jpg/800px-Space_Shuttle_Atlantis_approaching_the_Kennedy_Space_Center_to_land_following_STS-122.jpg");
        splash.setImageURL(imageSource);

        // coordinates and dimensions:
        int x = 100, y = x;
        int width = 500, height = width;

        // (x, y), width, height:
        graphics.create(x, y, width, height);

        graphics.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        // adding and centering the text:
        graphics.drawString("centered text", (x + width)/2, (y + height)/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            showSplashScreen();
        } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} // end of MainGUI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

You either need supply the image via the command line or the Jar manifest

**Update with some basics**

You must supply an image for the splash screen to.  If you don't, it will always be null.

There are two ways to do this

### 1. From the command line

```
java -splash:path/to/image.jpg {other command line options}
```

The image must reside within the context of the class loader for the application (such as an embedded resource).

### 2. The Manifest file

This is a little more difficult, but will result in a much simpler execution (as no one needs to remember to add the command line ;))...

Check out [Working with Manifest Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for more details.

How you create it depends on your environment.

For example, in Netbeans, you can set the splash screen property in the project properties dialog, under the `Application` node.

Comment: This is the link that I referred to as being "cryptic". I will try to find this "manifest file" and how to edit it then... I haven't encountered this before, but have found some information here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html.