# Animated Splash screen in Netbeans Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8, animated, dynamic-splash-screen

I am trying to make animated Gif Splash screen in java netbeans but it doesn't works.. so I use jpg or PNG files it works .. I want to use gif animated file in splash screen I am using `-splash:src/Images/sspp.PNG`  in VM options.. please tell some solutions so I am able to use animated splash screen.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001292/animated-gif-leads-to-splashscreen-being-null/23001820#23001820)?  Be careful which GIFs you use ;).  And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964323/how-do-i-use-splashscreen-without-throwing-a-nullpointerexception/15964345#15964345) might help

Comment: yes it is related to my Question I can't understand optimized gif and simple gif @MadProgrammer

Comment: An optimised gif is one which creates a series of small images which, when put together, represent the differences between each frame (each frame is added to the last), where as an unoptimised gif is one where each frame is a completely new image (it fully replaces the last frame)

Comment: ok now I try to make (unoptimized gif)  hope it works for me then I tell you..

Comment: You want an unoptimised gif ;)

Comment: I say (think) some thing wrong ?? @MadProgrammer

Comment: I read your previous comment as "make optimized gif" ;)

Comment: YES..... you are amazing man ...It works for me .. wwwaaaoOOOO. I am so happy because of @MadProgrammer and stackoverflow I learn some thing new..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that the problem comes down to two things...
1.Using the command line parameter (-splash), Java expects the image to be a file on the file system, whereas the manifest file expects it to be an embedded resource.
2.Java doesn't seem capable of playing optimised gifs, that is gifs whose frames represent the difference between the last and current frame, instead of a complete image (as far as the splash screen goes).

I tried using

[image]

and

[image: Pony02]

The first image failed, but the second worked, the difference, as near as I can tell, is the first is optimized and the second is not...