# Splash screen not display when execute by Jar File but it works when execute from Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Set application Splash Screen from `Project properties -> Run Option`

[image]

SplashScreen which draw by StartApp Class

```
   public class StartApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            splashInit();           // initialize splash overlay drawing parameters
            appInit();              // simulate what an application would do before starting
            if (mySplash != null) // check if we really had a spash screen
            {
                mySplash.close();   // we're done with it
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // begin with the interactive portion of the program
    Context.initialize();


}
static SplashScreen mySplash;                   // instantiated by JVM we use it to get graphics
static Graphics2D splashGraphics;               // graphics context for overlay of the splash image
static Rectangle2D.Double splashTextArea;       // area where we draw the text
static Rectangle2D.Double splashProgressArea;   // area where we draw the progress bar
static Font font;                               // used to draw our text

/**
 * just a stub to simulate a long initialization task that updates
 * the text and progress parts of the status in the Splash
 */
private static void appInit() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int progress = 0;
    splashProgress(0);
    while (progress < 100) {
        //Sleep for up to one second.
        splashText("Please wait... Application is starting " + progress + "%");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            break;
        }
        //Make random progress.
        progress += random.nextInt(20);
        splashProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
    }
}

/**
 * Prepare the global variables for the other splash functions
 */
private static void splashInit() {
    // the splash screen object is created by the JVM, if it is displaying a splash image

    mySplash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
    // if there are any problems displaying the splash image
    // the call to getSplashScreen will returned null

    if (mySplash != null) {
        // get the size of the image now being displayed
        Dimension ssDim = mySplash.getSize();
        int height = ssDim.height;
        int width = ssDim.width;

        // stake out some area for our status information
        splashTextArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(20, height * 0.91, width * .50, 25.);
        splashProgressArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(1.0, height * .87, width - 2, 3);

        // create the Graphics environment for drawing status info
        splashGraphics = mySplash.createGraphics();
        font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        splashGraphics.setFont(font);

        // initialize the status info
        splashText("Starting");
        splashProgress(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Display text in status area of Splash.  Note: no validation it will fit.
 * @param str - text to be displayed
 */
public static void splashText(String str) {
    if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible()) {   // important to check here so no other methods need to know if there
        // really is a Splash being displayed

        // erase the last status text
        splashGraphics.setPaint(new Color(248, 249, 250));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashTextArea);

        // draw the text
        splashGraphics.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        splashGraphics.drawString(str, (int) (splashTextArea.getX() + 10), (int) (splashTextArea.getY() + 15));

        // make sure it's displayed
        mySplash.update();
    }
}

/**
 * Display a (very) basic progress bar
 * @param pct how much of the progress bar to display 0-100
 */
public static void splashProgress(int pct) {
    if (mySplash != null && mySplash.isVisible()) {

        // Note: 3 colors are used here to demonstrate steps
        // erase the old one
        splashGraphics.setPaint(new Color(230, 230, 230));
        splashGraphics.fill(splashProgressArea);

        // draw an outline
        // Calculate the width corresponding to the correct percentage
        int x = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinX();
        int y = (int) splashProgressArea.getMinY();
        int wid = (int) splashProgressArea.getWidth();
        int hgt = (int) splashProgressArea.getHeight();

        int doneWidth = Math.round(pct * wid / 100.f);
        doneWidth = Math.max(0, Math.min(doneWidth, wid - 1));  // limit 0-width

        // fill the done part one pixel smaller than the outline
        splashGraphics.setPaint(new Color(21, 106, 151));
        splashGraphics.fillRect(x, y - 2, doneWidth, hgt + 1);

        // make sure it's displayed
        mySplash.update();
    }
 }
 }
```

Above code is to draw Splash Screen. Please tell why it not work in `jar file` while works in `Netbeans IDE`.

Comment: I suspect the image path changes when in JAR. Can you please unzip the jar and show its content (or at least the image paths)

Comment: `-splash` expects the image file to be external to your application, so it CAN'T reside within your `src` directory, it won't exist when the application is built/packaged.  Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964323/how-do-i-use-splashscreen-without-throwing-a-nullpointerexception/15964345#15964345) for some more details

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer for answer 
Yes you both are correct that jar CAN'T reside within your src directory. So my query is solved thanks again.

Comment: Thanks  @serg.nechaev also for right answer response.

Comment: Thanks for the example, after the correction it works fine without modification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commandline parameter `-splash:` represents a image file on the disk, you can not reference embedded resources (which you image has become).

You should NEVER use any path reference which contains `src` it simply won't exist once the program is built/packaged/exported.

I'd recommend using the manifest approach instead, as described in [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html), in the section titled "How to Use a JAR File to Display Splash Screen"

Netbeans actually has the ability to do this for you automatically, including packaging the image into the Jar and updating the manifest file for your

[image: Splash Screen Properties]